# Return "int * const" from a function

Tags: c++, constants

In the code below, why the returned pointer p is allowed to change? If f instead returns "const int *", then the compiler will complain type mis-match error at line "int *p =f()". Why does it do the same for "int * const"?

btw: I know there are memory leaks in the code, but that has nothing to do with the question.

```
int * const f() {
  return new int(23);
}
int main(){
  int * p=f();
  p= new int(35);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because what you are returning is a unmodifiable pointer - **not** the pointer to unmodifiable data.

Yes, the returned pointer is not modifable - but it will never be modified! You are modifying the different pointer, `p` - which just happen to have the same value as your unmodifiable (and unnamed) pointer which is now gone - this object is a temporary and forgotten as soon as the statement is completed.

This is why returning const-qualified simple types by value from functions has no sense and actually triggers a warning in some compilers.

Comment: this is true. you should use `int const *` instead of `int * const`.

Comment: in addition, `int const * const` will declare a pointer that is both constant in where it points to, as well as the actual value in that location

Answer (score 0):

> In the code below, why the returned pointer p is allowed to change?

Because the type of `p` is `int *`. Since the pointer is not const, it may be modified. If you want `p` to not be modifiable, then you must make it const: `int * const p`

> If f instead returns "const int *", then the compiler will complain type mis-match error at line "int *p =f()"

Pointer-to-const is not convertible to pointer-to-non-const. Such conversion is not allowed by the language because it would break const correctness.

> Why does it do the same for "int * const"?

I guess you mean to ask "Why does the compiler allow assigning `int * const` to a `int *` variable?"

Copying a const object to a non-const object does not break const-correctness. When `p` is non-const, it's OK to modify it and the const temporary returned by `f` remains unmodified through it's entire (short) lifetime.

Constness of a temporary is rarely meaningful, and so is returning a top-level const value.

Answer (score 0):

`*const` is a constant pointer while `const *` is a pointer to constant. The latter is immutable value; you can of course assign this value to a variable, like you would write `int x = 42;`. The former points at an immutable object, so assigning this to a variable that is supposed to point at a mutable object would presumably violate that object's constness.